# How to declare a template specialisation within function template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Suppose I have a class template

```
template<int I, int J> class bar { /* ... */ };
```

and want to use the following template template

```
template<template<int> class C>
struct foo { void func(some_type arg); };
```

with `C` equal to `bar` with the second template argument bound (fixed). One way to achieve this is

```
template<int J, template<int, int> class B>
struct use_foo_helper {
  template<int I> using BJ = B<I,J>;
  static void func(some_type arg) { foo<BJ>::func(arg); }
};
template<int J>
void foo_bar(some_type arg) { use_foo_helper<J,bar>::func(arg); }
```

However, creating an auxiliary class (`use_foo_helper`) just for this purpose is quite inconvenient. I rather would like to just define the function template `foo_bar`, but failed:

```
template<int J>
void foo_bar(some_type arg)
{
  // template<int I> using barJ = bar<I,J>;  // this appears to be illegal
  // for<barJ>::func(arg);
  foo< ??? >::func(arg);                     // what shall I put in place of ???
};
```

**Q** Is there a way to avoid the helper class? **Q** Is there a better design pattern that achieves the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following manner:

```
template <int I, int J>
class bar{};

template <template<int> class C>
struct foo
{
    static
    void func(some_type arg){}
};

template <int J>
class foo_bar
{
    template <int I>
    using barJ = bar<I, J>;

public:

    static
    void call(some_type arg)
    {
        foo<barJ>::func(arg);
    }
};
```

Example of using: `foo_bar</*...*/>::call(/*...*/);`.

But if you want only to fix one parameter of your class template it can be done simpler:

```
template <int J>
struct barJ
{
    template <int I>
    using type = bar<I, J>;
};
```

Example of using: `foo<barJ</*...*/>::type>::func(/*...*/);`.

Comment: You still use those auxiliary helper classes `foo_bar` and `barJ`. So are you saying, that those cannot be avoided? If so, can you prove this?

Comment: @Walter I'm sorry, I inattentively read your question. Yes, I think you cannot avoid the use of helper class. No, I can't prove this. But I know that you can't even declare a template as a member of a local class (see 14.5.2/2), so...